# MySQL query error #1064?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import my old database but this gave me some errors what makes it impossible im also searching on google for 30 minuts and i can't find any solution?

```
SQL-query:


CREATE TABLE `UG_blogs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ownerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY id(`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


MySQL meldt: Documentatie

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY id(`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT C' at line 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct default value is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
CREATE TABLE `UG_blogs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ownerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY id(`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a05d8).

EDIT:

You must be using an old-ish version of MySQL (okay, not that old, just pre-5.6).  Well, you can't default a `datetime` value (without a trigger), so you have to live with a `TIMESTAMP` value and learn to love the timestamp functions:

```
CREATE TABLE `UG_blogs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ownerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY id(`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: That gave me the following error: #1067 - Invalid default value for 'date'

Comment: I use: 5.5.44-MariaDB

But ill give it a shot

Comment: @MennovanHout . . . MariaDB *is* (basically) MySQL, so a 5.6 or later version should support `datetime` with a default.

Answer (score 0):

First solution : change datatype into timestamp like this

```
CREATE TABLE `UG_blogs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ownerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY id(`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The problem is : The Timestamp data type has a range of 1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC to 2038-01-19 03:14:07.

So the second solution is, don't change datetime datatype into timestamp. But you need a trigger to set default value.